# Automated Remote SQL Backup

Tags: backup, remote, sql

I'm looking for a program that can be scheduled(weekly) to back up a SQL database on a server and download it to my local machine, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT: i should have specified that the SQL database is on a remote server. I'm looking for a program that will connect, then backup to .sql, then download to my local windows machine.

Comment: It would be nice to know a few more details i.e. what type of database server and what OS you're using, local or remote servers etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have a daily requirement for (remote) database backups using SQL Server 2008. I use two PowerShell scripts (a client and a server) and have them running as scheduled tasks in Windows.

The script on the server calls the native SQL Server backup function that results in one databse being dumped to a file. This file is then made accessible (via web or ftp). The client script then requests this resource some time in the future.

It's not very pretty but it works.

The same 2-step process can be implemented by scheduling backup tools and FTP clients with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: I do something similar for my MySQL backups. I use a combination of winscp and putty command line. I connect to my server remotely with ssh and run a predefine command to create the dump, then i sftp to download, then i delete the dumps. I run these as scheduled tasks on windows (cron on Linux would work of course as well)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm looking for. I guess i should have specified that the SQL database is on a remote server. I'm looking for a program that will connect, then backup to .sql, then download to my local windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote machine can see a network share on your local machine, then you could use the network resilient copy feature in [SQL Backup Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/) to move the data from the remote to the local machine.  It will also handle the scheduling and alert you when backups are failing.

I should also add a note on full disclosure: I work on this product, there are other 3rd party backup products available.

Why do you want to copy it to your local machine, btw?  For disaster recovery, or some other use?

Answer (score 0):

You mention the database is remote. I assume you have control of the remote server, but maybe not.
Check out [ExpressMaint](http://expressmaint.codeplex.com/) You didn't say whether your instance is an express or regular version, or even if it is MSSQL, but you can use this to automate the backup, if so.

Then use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to automate the download at the location you want to download to. There is a windows version if you have to have that.

Additionally, I would script the use of [7z](http://7-zip.org/) to further compress the backup before downloading so your actual transfer might be only a fraction of the size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLBackupAndFTP](https://sqlbackupandftp.com), it can do exactly what you need, backup your remote SQL Server databases and send backups to selected destinations like Local or Network folders, NAS, FTP Server, Amazon S3, Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, Box, Azure Storage, OneDrive for Business or Backblaze B2. https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/how-to-backup-remote-sql-server-database